# Query to find problems with missing row pairs, given a partition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a table where information is being stored like so:

| Work Order | Employee | FunctionGroup | FunctionType | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WO1 | Emp1 | Group1 | Start | 7/27/23 09:00 |
| WO1 | Emp1 | Group1 | Stop | 7/27/23 10:00 |
| WO1 | Emp1 | Group1 | Start | 7/27/23 11:00 |
| WO1 | Emp1 | Group1 | Stop | 7/27/23 12:00 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| WO2 | Emp2 | Group2 | Start | 7/27/23 13:00 |
| WO2 | Emp2 | Group2 | Stop | 7/27/23 14:00 |
| WO2 | Emp2 | Group2 | Start | 7/27/23 15:00 |
| WO2 | Emp2 | Group2 | Stop | 7/27/23 16:00 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| WO3 | Emp3 | Group3 | Start | 7/27/23 17:00 (problem here: since the next row is also a Start, then this row should be returned) |
| WO3 | Emp3 | Group3 | Start | 7/27/23 18:00 |
| WO3 | Emp3 | Group3 | Start | 7/27/23 19:00 |
| WO3 | Emp3 | Group3 | Stop | 7/27/23 20:00 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| WO4 | Emp4 | Group4 | Stop | 7/27/23 17:00 (problem here: since the dataset for this partition starts with a Stop instead of a Start, then this row should be returned) |
| WO4 | Emp4 | Group4 | Start | 7/27/23 18:00 |
| WO4 | Emp4 | Group4 | Start | 7/27/23 19:00 |
| WO4 | Emp4 | Group4 | Stop | 7/27/23 20:00 |

For each work order, employee, and function group, an employee can insert a Start and a Stop row (this is basically how the partition is defined). They must always be in the order of Start then Stop and cannot be backwards. This data collection will all start on a specific date/time, so there is a clean point where all the data must come in beginning with a Start. They can insert these pairs as many times as the need to. I need to write a query that checks to see if there is a problem with the pairings and if so - return the first row where this problem appeared.

In the table above, the last 2 sections show a potential problem and the row that must be returned. The main challenge here is just figuring out how to determine which rows go together as a pair. One alternative way I am thinking of handling this is to simply insert a unique ID with every Start, then insert that same ID with every Stop. This might work, but for now I need a query that can show me problems for the test data I'm using.

Comment: Your data is meaningless without a column that defines the order - a set has no order or "first" row unless you define it. You have forgotten to show your expected results too.

Comment: a table is by definition unsorted so no query can determine which start belongs to which stop, so it will be impossible to get a query

Comment: There is a timestamp column further to the right guys!

Comment: I missed there was a scrollbar sorry - it would be easier to see if the data was in a proper tabular layout.

Comment: This is easily solvable with some aggregation and lag/lead - can you post your data in a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) or as *create/inserts*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So based on the expectation that the data should be in start/stop pairs, you can allocate a row number and then compare the expected FunctionType with the actual FunctionType, or rather, since you want the error to appear on the line before, the *next* FunctionType (using `LEAD`) with the expected FunctionType.

```
declare @TestData table (WorkOrder varchar(3), Employee varchar(4), FunctionGroup varchar(6), FunctionType varchar(5), [Timestamp] datetime)

insert into @TestData (WorkOrder, Employee, FunctionGroup, FunctionType, [Timestamp])
values
('WO1','Emp1','Group1','Start','7/27/23 09:00'),
('WO1','Emp1','Group1','Stop','7/27/23 10:00'),
('WO1','Emp1','Group1','Start','7/27/23 11:00'),
('WO1','Emp1','Group1','Stop','7/27/23 12:00'),
('WO2','Emp2','Group2','Start','7/27/23 13:00'),
('WO2','Emp2','Group2','Stop','7/27/23 14:00'),
('WO2','Emp2','Group2','Start','7/27/23 15:00'),
('WO2','Emp2','Group2','Stop','7/27/23 16:00'),
('WO3','Emp3','Group3','Start','7/27/23 17:00'),-- (problem here: since the next row is also a Start, then this row should be returned)
('WO3','Emp3','Group3','Start','7/27/23 18:00'),
('WO3','Emp3','Group3','Start','7/27/23 19:00'),
('WO3','Emp3','Group3','Stop','7/27/23 20:00'),
('WO4','Emp4','Group4','Stop','7/27/23 17:00'),-- (problem here: since the dataset for this partition starts with a Stop instead of a Start, then this row should be returned)
('WO4','Emp4','Group4','Start','7/27/23 18:00'),
('WO4','Emp4','Group4','Start','7/27/23 19:00'),
('WO4','Emp4','Group4','Stop','7/27/23 20:00');

with cte as (
  select *
    , row_number() over (partition by WorkOrder, Employee, FunctionGroup order by [Timestamp]) rn
    , lead(FunctionType) over (partition by WorkOrder, Employee, FunctionGroup order by [Timestamp]) FunctionTypeLead
  from @TestData
)
select WorkOrder, Employee, FunctionGroup, FunctionType, [Timestamp]
from cte
where rn%2 = 1 and FunctionTypeLead != 'Stop'
order by WorkOrder, Employee, FunctionGroup, [Timestamp];
```

Returns:

| WorkOrder | Employee | FunctionGroup | FunctionType | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WO3 | Emp3 | Group3 | Start | 2023-07-27 17:00:00.000 |
| WO4 | Emp4 | Group4 | Stop | 2023-07-27 17:00:00.000 |

Note: Providing the DDL+DML (as shown here) makes it much easier to answer.

Comment: Thanks Dale. This worked, but I'm going to implement the alternative, pre-emptive solution I mentioned in the question and when the need arises to do comprehensive analysis on the users' entries I'll use your answer as the basis for that. I appreciate your help though - I learned about the `LEAD` function thanks to you.